# How to add a new entity to the "regarding" section of the CRM App for Outlook?

Tags: dynamics-crm

This [msdn article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn946901.aspx) states that following feature for CRM App for Outlook:

> Create CRM contact or lead records for people on the From list that
>   aren’t already included in the CRM database. You can also create new
>   CRM records for any entity (record type), as long as the entity has
>   been enabled for mobile and for multi-entity search

When I click on "Change"  (when an email is being tracked) , I can see a few entities for which I can create new records, these are:  (Accounts-  Contacts- Leads - Opportunities - Cases). However I need to add Appointments and Tasks as well.

So I tried to apply the settings for these entities as mention in the above quote, adn I set the enabled for mobile as well as for mutli-entity search but still I couldn't see these two entities in my CRM APP for outlook. They are visible in CRM mutli-entity search though.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The "Convert" feature creates a new Opportunity, Case, Lead etc from the tracked email, and sets the email as "Regarding" that new record. While you can enable other entities to have activities attached to them, this won't add any special buttons to "Convert" emails to records of these entities. But you would see the new entity appear in the list of "Regarding" entities available to choose.

You cannot enable an activity to have activities attached to it. You can add a custom relationship, from Appointment to EMail for example, but that won't use the "Regarding" lookup.

Best option here would be to use an on-demand workflow for the email record. User would track the email, then go to run workflow > select the workflow for Appointment or Task and confirm. Workflow would create the new record, copying relevant fields from the email.